# What do tabs \t mean in Elm?

Tags: elm

I was messing around with Elm and I got this error message:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main                ( Main.elm )
Parse error at (line 3, column 1):
unexpected '\t'
expecting newline, spaces or end of input
```

Do tabs have special meaning in Elm, as they might in Python?

---

For example http://share-elm.com/sprout/53d1a38ae4b07afa6f98344d

```
main : Element
main = flow down
    [ leftAligned (toText "A")
    , leftAligned (toText "B")
    , leftAligned (toText "C")
  ]
```

Answer (score 5):

It is complaining that you are indenting using tabs rather than spaces.

You will see that the code works when you replace the tabs with spaces.

http://share-elm.com/sprout/53d1ad92e4b07afa6f983471

Comment: Incredible that it doesn't allow tabs as whitespace.

Comment: I agree. Most editors will automatically convert your tabs to spaces. Share Elm is one of the few that doesn't. It does try to do auto indent when you press enter but it doesn't work for the first thing you want to indent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any chance have added a tab space instead of a new line?